# show images from internal storage in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm saving images from camera and gallery(multi-select) to a folder in internal storage. I want to display those images in horizontal Recyclerview. In the row layout, there is a close button along with imageview. I want to delete the image(File) from internal storage when the close button is clicked. I've 2 problems:
**Problem 1:** When I select images(single or multiple) from gallery, the images are saving correctly but in Recyclerview, the image from gallery is shown in all position i.e. if there are 2 images in the folder and I select 1 image from gallery, then in Recyclerview all 3 positions will have the image from gallery only. 
**Problem 2:** How to delete images from folder when close button is clicked?

```css
//Recyclerview Adapter
public class RecycleImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> itemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecycleImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.imagelayout, parent, false);
        return new RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        for (int i= 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(itemList.get(i));
            holder.setImageView(uri);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        ImageView image, delbtn;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            delbtn = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.del);
            delbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setImageView(Uri uri){
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(uri).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Log.e("sammy_error"," "+errorDrawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, itemList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            itemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemList.size());

   //Here I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            File file = new File(itemList.get(position));
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
//in Fragment, code to load images

File directory = new File(file_path);
        File newfile[] = directory.listFiles();
        //finalImages is ArrayList<String>  
        if(finalImages!=null )finalImages.clear();

        for (int i= 0; i < newfile.length; i++) {
            String path = "file://"+newfile[i].getAbsolutePath();
            finalImages.add(path);
        }

        recyladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I'm very sorry, I cannot understand your problem. Could you please explain in detail so that I can help you in a better way?

Comment: I want to show images from a specific folder let's say "Arc" in Internal Storage in Recyclerview. I'm saving images from gallery as well as camera in the folder Arc. After saving image (either from gallery or camera) into Arc, I use the above code in fragment to display images.

Comment: So the process is like this: Camera Intent -> Captured image -> saved in Arc -> Fragment code to show images in recyclerview. Or Gallery -> selected image(s) -> saved in Arc -> Fragment code to show images in recyclerview.

Comment: @SomnathPal can u check whether finalImages contains same paths or different paths?

Comment: @SomnathPal - Ok, thanks for explaining. As far as I have understood, your images are repeating in the `RecyclerView`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But when I add images from gallery. @VarunKumar

Comment: @SomnathPal can u post the saving part of the image when u r selecting from gallery?

Comment: @SomnathPal - Ok. Are you using separate AsyncTasks for loading each image?

Comment: The saving of images code for Camera and Gallery http://www.hastebin.com/osuyawewas.js @Raghavendra

Comment: No, I'm using same method for both @VarunKumar

Comment: @SomnathPal - Could you please share the code where you load images from camera and gallery?

Comment: @SomnathPal did u check that filpaths in finalImages are same or different after adding from gallery?

Comment: Full code here http://www.hastebin.com/wasezuriju.java
PS. I checked file paths in finalImages (Arraylist) have correct path of images @VarunKumar

Comment: @SomnathPal In onBindViewHolder why r u using for loop? Can u remove that and use position param and try?

Comment: I'm getting path of images from arraylist<String> finalImages in fragment. So in for loop I'm converting string path to Uri and then using picasso setting those images. Let me try your idea @Raghavendra

Comment: Why don't u use position param of onbinndviewholder?

Comment: Amazing. It seems that using for loop was producing the fault. After removing it and using "position" params, its working perfectly. Thanks so much man!!  @Raghavendra

Comment: @SomnathPal cool:) Glad that helped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127624/discussion-between-somnath-pal-and-raghavendra).

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't understand your first part explain it more.

and in 2nd part it is very simple just set the image path as imageView tag.

```
imageView.setTag(imageAbsolutePath);
```

and when you click on image get the tag from image view and convert it to file like this

```
File path = new File(imageView.getTag().toString());
path.delete();
```